# Identify the succulent

Tags: identification, succulents, hanging-plant

This succulent was presented to me. The person who presented it to me just gave 2/3 strings of the plant and asked me to plant it in a hanging pot.
[image]

[image]

Its leaves are slightly reddish on the backside.
[image]

Currently, there are some flowers on it, tiny white-violetish.
[image]

This is all I've got. I do not think it is [String of Nickels](https://www.google.com/search?q=string%20of%20nickels&client=ubuntu&hs=6we&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL6JrPq8vuAhUzzTgGHVNgCeYQ_AUoAXoECCEQAw&biw=1319&bih=670). Can anyone identify what it is ?

Comment: That soil looks a little hard, do you have some potting mix you can use?

Comment: I have some vermicompost.. but I am not sure if I should use it. Should I put it there?

Comment: That is not going to help unless you break up the chunks in that soil.  Just get some potting mix.

Comment: Okay, will do so. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The succulent that you have is called Plectranthus Prostratus. It is also called String of Pillows. Transplant it to a more gritty medium, succulents like loose soil.

Comment: Ohh yeah..Thanks for the id.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a *Kalanchoe*. Unfortunately that doesn't narrow it down much, because there are 125 species of *Kalanchoe*. Many of them are common as houseplants.

It looks similar to this unidentified Kalanchoe from [the Epic Gardening article, "How to Propagate Kalanchoe"](https://www.epicgardening.com/how-to-propagate-kalanchoe/). This one appears to have an upright growth form, more shrub-like than vine-like.

[image]

Or it could be *Kalenchoe uniflora*, as seen in a screenshot from the Youtube video, [Kalanchoe uniflora Houseplant Care](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J29bbx6SNHM).

[image]

Here's a cultivar of *Kalenchoe uniflora*, 'Freedom Bells' from [Dave's Garden](https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/215027/#b)
[image]

None of those options has the all-over reddish tint that your plant has. But your plant looks pretty unhappy and stressed, and some plants develop a red tint when they're unhappy. If you can get your plant in better health, its color may change a bit. Or the red color could be due to sun exposure - essentially the plant equivalent of a tan, and not necessarily a problem. Kalanchoes can handle full sun. Either way, your plant would probably appreciate some better soil. As with all succulents, make sure the potting mix drains well, and let it dry out between waterings. The easiest way to kill a succulent is to keep its potting mix wet all the time. Here's another [Kalanchoe care guide](https://worldofsucculents.com/kalanchoe-uniflora-coral-bells/).

FYI, according to [VetMeds.com](https://vetmeds.org/pet-poison-control-list/kalanchoe/), Kalanchoes are poisonous to pets, so if you have a free-roaming pet, be sure to keep this plant out of their reach.

Comment: These seems close. I will do as both of you have suggested. Thanks for the links.